# case statement in WHERE clause with column name as the condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to do a select in a where clause, where the result of the case statement is the column name.

Here's what I've tried:

```
declare @lang int -- this is passed to the stored procedure
declare @productname nvarchar(300) -- this is passed to the stored procedure

select productid from products where

    case 
    when @lang = 1 then producten
    when @lang = 2 then productit
    when @lang = 3 then productde
    end product like @productname
```

So, for english (@lang = 1) I want:

```
select productid from products where producten like @productname
```

I'm getting errors though and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to phrase it like this:

```
case when @lang = 1 then producten
     when @lang = 2 then productit
     when @lang = 3 then productde
end like @productname
```

Or, perhaps more clearly:

```
when @lang = 1 and producten like @productname or
     @lang = 2 and productit like @productname or
     @lang = 3 and productde like @productname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write query as:

```
declare @lang int -- this is passed to the stored procedure
declare @productname nvarchar(300) -- this is passed to the stored procedure

select productid from products 
where 1= case when @lang = 1 and @productname like producten then 1
              when @lang = 2 and @productname like productit then 1
              when @lang = 3 and @productname like productde then 1
         end
```